# Continuous methods php

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I see in codeigniter a sintaxis method->other_method->other_method_again. example:

```
$this->db->select()->join()->findAll();
```

When i try

```
class MyClass{
       public function bla(){
             echo "bla";
       }
       public function other(){
             echo "other";
       }
}

$message = new MyClass();

$message->bla()->other();
```

Return:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function other()
```

as I can do what codeigniter?

Comment: Spend 10 minutes writing an informative answer with examples for it to be closed. Makes me not want to answer on SO.

Comment: @Torra sometimes it is good to post a tentative answer first and then edit it or improve it afterwards

Comment: I apologize, but I do not speak English and never (never) found something similar to what I was looking on page ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is called [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) (popularised by jQuery chaining) and is achieved if you

`return $this`

from each method

for your example:

```
class MyClass{
       public function bla(){
             echo "bla";
             return $this; // enable method chaining
       }
       public function other(){
             echo "other";
             return $this; // enable method chaining
       }
}
```

The reason this works is the same the following works:

```
$instance->method1();
$instance->method2();
```

Here each method is called on an `$instance` **but** if each method returns the actual `$instance` back which is the same as `$this`, then one can combine the statements like this ("*chain*" them):

```
$instance->method1()/* returns $instance and can be used again*/->method2();
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: thanks and I apologize for repeating the question but i don't speak english and he could not find anything like this page